# Is there any method to use material UI icons?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI table but unfortunately its font colour is white so by which i cannot see the text but on selecting the text i can see the data, and there is an issue with icons too, although i had installed the libraries all well. Below is the code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import '@material-ui/core';
import '@material-ui/icons';
import '@material-ui/lab';

export default function AdminXnaLog() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); //table data
  const [iserror, setIserror] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState([])
  var columns = [
    {title: "id", field: "_id", hidden: true},
    {title: "Member No", field: "memberno"},
    {title: "Name", field: "name"},
    {title: "Surname", field: "surname"}
    ]
   
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBooks() {
          const response = await fetch('/xnalogget');
          const json = await response.json();
          setData(json.xl);
          console.log(json.xl)
      }
      fetchBooks();
  },[]);
  
  
  return (
   
    <MaterialTable
  title="XNA Logs"
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  style={{ backgroundColor: "white", margin: "3%" }}  // editable={{
/>
    
  )
}
```

This is the picture in which the font color and icons are not working.

[image]

Comment: Please check the [Material page](https://mui.com/components/material-icons/) to check, how to include a particular icon from the material icons library.

Comment: Where are you expecting icons to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you want to use icons? You don't use the icons prop (`icons=` passed into the component) for MaterialTable at all.

From the documentation:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };

<MaterialTable
  icons={tableIcons}
  ...
/>
```

https://material-table.com/#/docs/install

And you can use them by name inside the table, with an action for example:

```
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Do save operation
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

where `icon` is a string value referencing the icon.

You can also just another component in, like in this answer: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions

Comment: and why the font colour is white? as the background color is also white so the data is not visible. What are the ways in which we can customize the style of the table . Like style={{}} (inlne styling) is not working here/ neither effecting the rows data.

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems to be black by default, possibly inherited from elsewhere in your project?

You can set it in the options prop, assuming they've made the field available to you (you can manually do it if they haven't but in this case you can easily change the text color). See: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling `options={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#01579b',
          color: '#FFF'
        }
      }}` changes the header

Comment: What is the manual method for it? or how to use that options prop

Comment: ok ok Thanks I got it